# send click to topmost window in compact framework using c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have an application which is in normal mode, now from that application i want to send click message to another window (say internet explorer). I want to click where mouse cursor is pointing right now with respect to screen and that click should be handled by internet explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Win32 API call `mouse_event` -- I do not know if there is a .NET equivalent, but it can be used to do just what you want, i.e. fake a mouse click at the current location. To do this call it with the LEFTDOWN and LEFTUP flags.

Look it up on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/mouse_event.html?diff=y) for how to call from C# and VB.NET.

Comment: ya I did it, by using same thing i.e. mouse_event